# why 100% height of a div in print / preview in chrome is not working?

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, printing

Here is the example:

http://jsbin.com/oxunu3/6

Have a print preview in chrome and firefox. Why chrome does not like the 100% height? Any hack or something?

Comment: Doesn't Chrome *not* have print preview?

Comment: type about:flags in chrome and you can enable it. Google is your friend, my friend.

Comment: I've noticed this too, and am really interested in finding out why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Webkit browsers are known to have their own little quirks which divert from the supposed way of doing things. I changed `min-height:` to `height:` *or* used `::before { content: <img src="spacer.gif" width="1" height="100%" />"; }`and it worked.

It looks like Google or Apple is trying to save people ink.